# Is there a desktop text editor or an editor plugin which loads and saves files via a REST API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, text-editor, remote-development

I'm currently building a webapp where users can also write and edit code. In addition to the web based editor a I want to enable them to edit the files in a local desktop editor. However, since the code isn't stored in files, but in a database, I can not use the default VS Code remote development system.

So is there a desktop text editor or an editor plugin which can directly load and save files via a REST API or GraphQL API?

Comment: you can write a remote workspace interface for VSC, this extension translates read/write/rename/delete on a file system to REST requests

Comment: @rioV8 Is this interface documented somewhere? It sounded like the whole remote work infrastructure is proprietary and not really meant to be used outside of their implementation.

Comment: read the VSC API doc starting at `registerFileSystemProvider`

Comment: Cool, thanks for the pointer! Microsoft even provides an example extension: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/fsprovider-sample